# button dynamic background color with rounded edges

Tags: android, radio-button

I managed to have rounded edge for my button.

I also managed to have a dynamic background color (taken from a webservice).

**The problem is when doing this :**

```
   btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radio_button_selector);
   btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(currentQuestion.backgroundColorButton));
```

One overrides the other, therefore I cannot have rounded edges AND dynamic background color.

I cannot use a dynamic color in the selector (as it's a static XML).

I cannot set the rounded edges programmatically (the method doesn't exists as far as I know).

How do I do ?

Comment: easy way to do that is to make another selector with different color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 String backgroundColor= "#fc0000"; // set dynamic color here

 btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
```

another Examples:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
drawable.setStroke(5, Color.MAGENTA); 
drawable.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
btnBlackColor.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: That was it. just had to add drawable.setCornerRadius(8);

Answer (score 0):

**use this :-**

```
final int color = Color.parseColor(homeCatPOJOS.get(position).getColor());
```

then implement it in background color :-

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radio_button_selector);
btn.setBackgroundColor(color));
```

I think you are getting color code in `String`, first convert into `int` then implement it.
And for round edges make XML file for it and implement it statically.